# Setting values at negative indexes

Tags: python, doubly-linked-list

For this LinkedList class I'm creating. What would be the best way to go about fixing my `__setitem__` method body?

```
class LinkedList:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, val, prior=None, next=None):
            self.val = val
            self.prior = prior
            self.next  = next

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = LinkedList.Node(None) # sentinel node (never to be removed)
        self.head.prior = self.head.next = self.head # set up "circular" topology
        self.length = 0


### prepend and append

    def prepend(self, value):
        n = LinkedList.Node(value, prior=self.head, next=self.head.next)
        self.head.next.prior = self.head.next = n
        self.length += 1

    def append(self, value):
        n = LinkedList.Node(value, prior=self.head.prior, next=self.head)
        n.prior.next = n.next.prior = n
        self.length += 1


### subscript-based access ###

    def _normalize_idx(self, idx):
        nidx = idx
        if nidx < 0:
            nidx += len(self)
            if nidx < 0:
                nidx = 0
        return nidx

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        """Implements `x = self[idx]`"""
        nidx = self._normalize_idx(idx)
        currNode = self.head.next
        for i in range(nidx):
            currNode = currNode.next
        if nidx >= len(self):
            raise IndexError
        return currNode.val


    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        """Implements `self[idx] = x`"""
        nidx = self._normalize_idx(idx)
        currNode = self.head.next
        if nidx >= len(self):
            raise IndexError
        for i in range(nidx):
            currNode = currNode.next
        currNode.val = value

    def __delitem__(self, idx):
        """Implements `del self[idx]`"""
        nidx = self._normalize_idx(idx)
        currNode = self.head.next
        if nidx >= len(self):
            raise IndexError
        for i in range(nidx):
            currNode = currNode.next
        currNode.prior.next = currNode.next #unlink currNode from its neighbors
        currNode.next.prior = currNode.prior
```

Using this test case

```
     # test subscript-based access
from unittest import TestCase
import random

tc = TestCase()
data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lst = LinkedList()
for d in data:
    lst.append(d)

for i in range(len(data)):
    tc.assertEqual(lst[i], data[i])

with tc.assertRaises(IndexError):
    x = lst[100]

with tc.assertRaises(IndexError):
    lst[100] = 0

with tc.assertRaises(IndexError):
    del lst[100]

lst[1] = data[1] = 20
del data[0]
del lst[0]

for i in range(len(data)):
    tc.assertEqual(lst[i], data[i])

data = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100)]
lst = LinkedList()
for d in data:
    lst.append(d)

for i in range(len(data)):
    lst[i] = data[i] = random.randint(101, 200)
for i in range(50):
    to_del = random.randrange(len(data))
    del lst[to_del]
    del data[to_del]

for i in range(len(data)):
    tc.assertEqual(lst[i], data[i])

for i in range(0, -len(data), -1):
    tc.assertEqual(lst[i], data[i])
```

I'd get an Assertion error saying these random values aren't equal at the end, 178 != 195. What would fix this?

Comment: Please give a [mcve], and how would you define *"best"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `__delitem__` doesn't decrement your length. So when you use `self.length` in the `_normalize_idx` for negative values it breaks. If you test negative numbers before you do the `del` test you will probably find it works fine.

```
tc.assertEqual(len(lst), len(data))
for i in range(50):
    to_del = random.randrange(len(data))
    del lst[to_del]
    del data[to_del]
tc.assertEqual(len(lst), len(data))   # AssertionError: 100 != 50
```

So when you do:

```
lst[-1]
```

This translates to through `_normalize_idx` to:

```
lst[99]
```

Which just happens to be coincidentally close to twice around your linked list, it's off by 1 because of your sentinel `None`:

```
>>> print('LinkedList([', ', '.join(str(lst[i]) for i in range(len(lst))), '])')
LinkedList([ 137, 138, 101, 186, 138, 156, 126, 195, 172, 128, 119, 193, 
117, 126, 124, 106, 191, 104, 177, 141, 101, 152, 156, 184, 173, 166, 137,
169, 106, 131, 173, 119, 169, 131, 157, 106, 171, 137, 154, 162, 126, 179,
115, 144, 189, 180, 179, 193, 105, 131, None, 137, 138, 101, 186, 138, 156,
                                        ^^^^
126, 195, 172, 128, 119, 193, 117, 126, 124, 106, 191, 104, 177, 141, 101,
152, 156, 184, 173, 166, 137, 169, 106, 131, 173, 119, 169, 131, 157, 106,
171, 137, 154, 162, 126, 179, 115, 144, 189, 180, 179, 193, 105 ])
```

Hope that helps.